# The target "GetBuiltProjectOutputRecursive" does not exist in the project when referencing netstandard library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-standard, .net-standard-1.4

I have a Xamarin Android project, and I am trying to add a reference to my own netstandard1.4 class library. When I add the reference, my Android application will no longer build. I get `error MSB4057: The target "GetBuiltProjectOutputRecursive" does not exist in the project.`

If I remove the reference, my android project builds fine.

The class library is a brand new library that I just created. It doesn't contain any actual code yet.

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

UPDATE: If I add a reference to my dll using the "Browse" function, it works. I only get the error when I add the reference to the project in my solution.

Comment: This appears to be a race condition. As sometimes the build works, and sometimes it does not. If I keep retrying, the project will eventually build.

Comment: More specifically, are you using Visual Studio 15.2 or 15.3? If you are on 15.2, have you tried 15.3(Preview Channel)?

Comment: I am using 15.2. I have not tried in 15.3 yet.

Comment: Please try 15.3 as you can install a "Preview" version of Visual Studio. https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/ If this still occurs,  please upload a minimal viable sample to your question.

Comment: I'm still running into this in 15.3.3, and no amount of building seems to result in success yet.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in 15.4